# Rails: A Rating Up or Down Counter, Lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, counter, rating

I am currently trying to create a rating counter that has a up or down feature to it. I am confused to if I should add a column to my post to show that a person likes the post or create a separate model to show the rating counter but the counter belongs to the post. Something along the lines of Reddit or even Stackoverflow's. Also, how would I start on this rating counter, to whichever method is the right method? Thank you everyone.

**Edit - Currently stuck on how to move on from here**

**Rating**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post_id, :user_id, :rating
  has_many :post
  has_many :users

  validates :post_id, presence: true

end
```

**Rating Controller**

```
class RatingController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.rating_count = @post.rating_count + 1
  end
end
```

**Rating Form**

```
<%=form_tag @rating do %>
<%=submit_tag :Rating%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a separate model, which will store user_id, post_id and a rating columns.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :users
end
```

Then you`ll be able to fetch all rating for the appropriate Post, the Post`s rating for the appropriate user and so on.

You can even create a polymorphic relation to provide ratings functionality for other models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, as: :rateable
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rateable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :users
end
```

Comment: Can you look at the edit? I am confused to where to go about it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can define 2 mothods in PostsController, like rate_up and rate_down. In each one you should check for authenticated user and for a valid post, and then create a Rating model depending on which method is called. The paths for rating a post would be for example /posts/:id/rate_up and /posts/:id/rate_down.